# Clean for loop for matching elements

Tags: c++, algorithm, design-patterns

I find that a lot of code I write in general is following a pattern of "loop through this container and do X to elements that match some criteria".

which often looks like this:

```
std::vector<int> theList(10);
std::iota(theList.begin(), theList.end(), 0);

for (auto i : theList)
{
    if ((i % 2) == 0)
    {
        //Do something with i
    }
}
```

I don't like the `if` statements in these cases - they're ugly and detract from what is really happening in the logic of the loop.

What I'd like is a better way of doing this so the heart of the problem is expressed nicely.

My best attempt so far isn't all that nice:

```
std::vector<int> theList(10);
std::iota(theList.begin(), theList.end(), 0);

auto criteria = [](const int& i) -> bool { return (i % 2) == 0; };

for (auto it = std::find_if(theList.begin(), theList.end(), criteria);
     it != theList.end();
     it = std::find_if(++it, theList.end(), criteria)
     )
{
    std::cout << *it << ", ";
}
```

It feels like this pattern should make its way in to `std::algorithm` in a cleaner way.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: There is `std::remove_if` to filter the list, same as `filter` higher-order function in other languages. But the filtered list would require separate memory to be stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a simple higher-order function for this:

```
template <typename Range, typename Predicate, typename F>
void for_items_matching(Range&& r, Predicate&& p, F&& f)
{
    for(auto&& x : r)
    {
        if(p(x)) { f(x); }
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
auto criteria = [](const int& i) -> bool { return (i % 2) == 0; };
for_items_matching(theList, criteria, [](auto&& item)
{
    std::cout << item << ", ";
})
```

---

With some refactoring and helper classes/function you could end up with something like:

```
for_items_of(theList)
    .matching(criteria)
    .execute([](auto&& item){ std::cout << item << ", "; });
```

---

Another possibility is looking at the upcoming [Ranges TS](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/n4569.pdf).

Comment: Thanks.  This seems to be about the best we can do at the moment.  Very similar answer to @vlad-from-moscow below (I think I'll use both), but you just got in first for get accepted answer :)

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood you correctly then what you need is the standard algorithm `std::for_each_if`. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>

template<class InputIterator, class Predicate, class Function>
Function for_each_if(InputIterator first,
                     InputIterator last,
                     Predicate predicate,
                     Function f)
{
    for (; first != last; ++first)
    {
        if (predicate(*first)) f(*first);
    }

    return f;
}

int main()
{
    int a[10];

    std::iota(std::begin(a), std::end(a), 0);

    for_each_if(std::begin(a), std::end(a),
        [](int x) { return x % 2 == 0;  },
        [](int x) { std::cout << x << ", "; });

    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
0, 2, 4, 6, 8,
```

However actually there is no such standard algorithm in C++ though I made a suggestion to include it in the Standard.:)